# View permission names of a specific app on android ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, permissions

Hello I am pretty basic new to Java and Android world. Currenty working on a project of my own. Basically I need to show permission names of a specific app on a ListView.

Though I already implemented it and it working well. but on my list view I am getting permission names as something like "android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"

But I want to show that string as "Manage Accounts"

Here is the code block that I have written.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(appPackageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        //Get Permissions
        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

        if(requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {

                Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);

                itemname.add(requestedPermissions[i]);

            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It lists permission names as "android.permission.PERMISSION_NAME" or something like that. But I want to show them as a bit like human readable. for example showing "android.permission.PERMISSION_NAME" as "Permission Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo("ashish.app.com.getpremissions", PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        //Get Permissions
        String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

        if (requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {

                Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);

                String[] last = requestedPermissions[i].toString().split("\\.");

                String lastOne = last[last.length - 1];

                if (!lastOne.contains("_")) {
                    Log.e("app", "permissions is----" + lastOne.toLowerCase());
                } else {
                    String[] permissions = lastOne.split("_");
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int index = 0; index < permissions.length; index++) {
                        sb.append(permissions[index].toLowerCase());
                        sb.append(" ");
                    }
                    Log.e("app", "permissions is----" + sb.toString());
                }

                // itemname.add();

            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting a string like `"android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"` to `"Manage Accounts"` is possible. But it cannot be safe to apply a same algorithm (removing `android.permission.`, then replacing `_` whit space and the convert string to lowercase) to all permissions.

If you are sure that all permission names follow a same rule you can do something like this:

```
String permissionName = "android.permission.PERMISSION_NAME";
        permissionName = permissionName.replace("android.permission.", "");
        String[] words = permissionName.split("_");
        String newPermissionName = "";
        for(String word: words){
            newPermissionName+= word.substring(0,1) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ";
        }
```

(Maybe it is not the best way but it works)

Also because the permissions are static, you can use a `HashMap` to store a name for each permission:

```
map.put("android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS", "Manage Accounts");
```

By this way you are not worry about different permission styles and also you can use your desired permission name.

Comment: I also thought of same way. but some other names are in different format. so didn't used that. but the above solution worked.